# conversation type inbox messages between two users for a website

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to achieve a conversation type inbox messages between two users in which the conversations will be group between two users and displayed on the inbox page and when clicked on the conversation the overall chat history will be displayed between two users ....
I have a database schema but failed to group the conversations between two users.I need a query for acheiving this Thank you 
here are my tables.

1.**Users:**

- id
- username
- password

2.**conversations:**

- conversation_id
- from_user
- to_user

3.**messages:**

- message_id
- conversation_id
- user_id
- message_text
- message_date
- seen

so if someone know how to achieve this query then help me also changes to my schema will be appreciated thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can get all conversations of current user with last message by conversation using query that looks like the following:

```
SELECT users.id,
       users.name,
       messages.conversation_id,
       messages.message_id,
       messages.message_text,
       messages.message_date,
       messages.seen
FROM
  (SELECT conversations.conversation_id,
          IF(conversations.from_user = <current_user_id>, conversations.to_user, conversations.from_user) AS interlocutor_id,
          max(messages.message_id) AS last_message_id
   FROM conversations
   LEFT JOIN messages ON conversations.conversation_id = messages.conversation_id
   WHERE convesations.from_id = <current_user_id>
     OR conversations.to_id = <current_user_id>
   GROUP BY conversations.conversation_id) AS t
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = t.intercolutor_id
LEFT JOIN messages ON messages.message_id = t.last_message_id
```

If you need get all conversations of current user with last indox messages using:

```
SELECT users.id,
       users.name,
       messages.conversation_id,
       messages.message_id,
       messages.message_text,
       messages.message_date,
       messages.seen
FROM
  (SELECT conversations.conversation_id,
          IF(conversations.from_user = <current_user_id>, conversations.to_user, conversations.from_user) AS interlocutor_id,
          max(messages.message_id) AS last_message_id
   FROM conversations
   LEFT JOIN messages ON conversations.conversation_id = messages.conversation_id
   WHERE (convesations.from_id = <current_user_id>
          OR conversations.to_id = <current_user_id>)
     AND messages.user_id <> <current_user_id>
   GROUP BY conversations.conversation_id) AS t
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = t.intercolutor_id
LEFT JOIN messages ON messages.message_id = t.last_message_id
```

But I think than better way if you will rewrite your database scheme and you will add id of last message in 'conversations' table. It will make the query more optimal

UPDATED:

If you need get list of all users that have conversation with current user:

```
SELECT t.conversation_id,
       users.id,
       users.name
FROM
  (SELECT conversation_id,
          IF(from_user = <current_user_id>, to_user, from_user) AS interlocutor_id          
   FROM conversations   
   WHERE from_id = <current_user_id>
     OR to_id = <current_user_id>) AS t
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = t.intercolutor_id
```

P.S. You must replace `<current_user_id>` to actual indentifier of current user

Comment: i not getting your answer also its kind of complicated sir and giving me an error .. what i want to acheive is to list the usernames excluding itself to which the person has conversations with can you please elaborate it thank you

Comment: Do you need only usernames?

Comment: I had add new querty to my answer

Comment: "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS t
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = t.intercolutor_id LIMIT 0, 25' at line 9"

This is the error which the query is giving to me

Comment: Did you replaced `<current_user_id>` to actual indentifier of current user? Are you sure that the column name of user indetifier is 'id'?

Comment: yes sir i have replaced the current_user_id with the current user and yeah the column name is id

Comment: I check this query and its sytax is correct. You should check column names and table names in query. Parhaps they is different in your database scheme

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT conversation FROM
        conversations

WHERE (conversations.from_user = <user parameter>
OR conversations.to_user = <user parameter>) 
AND conversations.from_user <> conversations.to_user
```

Comment: i have two conversations currently and in each conversation two users are talking .. what i want is to group the conversations in which the current user is participating according to the other users username but your query is returning four records including the current user itself but i like it to make it group like that of facebook messager

Comment: It is unclear what your goal is. You said in other comments that you only need usernames, but here you say you want to group conversations. The two things will have different queries to provide te data. Please decide which of them is the requirement

Comment: i want to group the messages on their usernames to which users the current user is talking to just like facebook messanger thats what i want to achieve

Comment: no sir you are not getting me let me explain ... lets say we have 4 users and 3 conversations ... in conversation1 user1(smith) is talking to users2(john) and in conversation2 user2(john) is talking to user3(michael) and in conversation3 user1(smith) is talking to user3(michael) so when user1 login to his account there will be two conversation in his inbox one with the name of john and other with the name of michael and so on  ... This is what i want

Comment: What if user1 has more than one converaation with user2? And do you want to get conversation id in results, username, or both?